# Which delegate method I should use to respond to clicks on a text field?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I want to open a panel when the user clicks on a text field. I think I should use a delegate method that responds to the click event. I found that the

```
- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

method does not work, and that the

```
- (void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

method works, but only when I edit the text in the text field, not then I click it. If I edit the text again, this method does not work. Why?

---

Sorry, I think I want to use this on mac , not on iphone,How to do with it with cocoa?

Answer (score 5):

The `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` delegate method only gets triggered when the user starts editing the text inside the `UITextField`, as the method name implies.

If you want to trigger a method when the `UITextField` is touched, you should try this:

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldTouched:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void) textFieldTouched:(id)sender {
    // Display the panel
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I want to use this on mac , not on iphone,How to do with it with cocoa?

Comment: @jin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684166/which-delegate-method-should-i-use-to-respond-to-clicks-on-an-nstextfield/4473352#4473352 has pretty good reply, have a look.

Answer (score 3):

The correct delegate method name is

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

From the documentation:

> This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just became the first responder.