# Which delegate method should I use to respond to clicks on an NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I am trying to respond to a `click` within a `textfield`. When the click occurs, I am going to open a `panel`. My initial thought was to use a `delegate` method to respond to the `click` event - but I found that:

This method doesn't work:

```
(void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

This method *does* work, but only when I actually *edit* the text within the text field, not when I first click it. And - if I edit the text a second time, this method stops working:

```
(void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

---

I could use as much detail as possible - or a code example, ideally. I know that an `nstextfield` inherits from `NSControl`, which has a `mouseDown` event. Is there a similar way to respond to the event with a `textfield`, also?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680863/which-delegate-method-i-should-use-to-respond-to-clicks-on-a-text-field

Comment: I agreed with you, but reading the other question, it appears that it isn't. This is a Mac question; the other is an iPhone question.

Comment: Yes , I think this is my question , I put it error location before.sorry!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `NSTextField` inherits from the `NSControl` class, it also inherits the `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*) theEvent` method.

Comment: I found that nstextfield inherits from the NSControl class , I also found that The NSController class have the method mouseDown ,but I don't know how to use it in my file, Thanks a lot .

Comment: You can simply override the mouseDown event in the NSTextField class, as follows:

@implementation NSTextField 
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*) theEvent {
 // your code here
}
@end

Comment: overriding mouseDown: is not enough for editable NSTextField, as once the field editor (a NSTextView*) is activated in the text field, it is "front" and it gets the mouseDown: events! So mouseDown: will work once, but not several time in a row... And overriding mouseDown: in the field editor is *very* tricky.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to have an `NSTextField` call a delegate function upon clicking it today, and thought this basic code might be useful. Note that `NSTextField` already has a delegate and that in SDK v10.6, the delegate already has a protocol associated with it. Note that if you don't care about protocols, compiler warnings, etc., you don't need the protocol and property declarations or the getter and setter.

```
MouseDownTextField.h:

#import <Appkit/Appkit.h>
@class MouseDownTextField;

@protocol MouseDownTextFieldDelegate <NSTextFieldDelegate>
-(void) mouseDownTextFieldClicked:(MouseDownTextField *)textField;
@end

@interface MouseDownTextField: NSTextField {
}
@property(assign) id<MouseDownTextFieldDelegate> delegate;
@end

MouseDownTextField.m:
#import "MouseDownTextField.h"

@implementation MouseDownTextField
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
  [self.delegate mouseDownTextFieldClicked:self];
}

-(void)setDelegate:(id<MouseDownTextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
  [super setDelegate:delegate];
}

-(id)delegate {
  return [super delegate];
}

AppDelegate.h:
@interface AppDelegate <MouseDownTextFieldDelegate>
...
@property IBOutlet MouseDownTextField *textField;
...

AppDelegate.m:
...
  self.textField.delegate = self;
...
-(void)mouseDownTextFieldClicked:(MouseDownTextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"Clicked");
  ...
}
...
```

If you're building with 10.5 SDK, don't have the protocol inherit from `NSTextFieldDelegate`.