# adding click action to NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How do I attach a event to a NSTextField for when I click on it? Are there any examples out there?

Comment: When the user clicks on the text field or when the user enters the text field (e.g. by clicking inside it or typing Tab)?

Comment: When the user clicks on the text field.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684166/which-delegate-method-i-should-use-to-respond-to-clicks-on-a-nstextfield

Comment: have you get any solution , i am also finding an idea to do it???

Answer (score 18):

```
NSClickGestureRecognizer *click = [[NSClickGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myTextFieldClicked:)];
[self.myTextField addGestureRecognizer:click];
```

Comment: Great solution. No need to subclass.

Comment: i really like this one, but seems not working for a static text field that can not be selected or edited, really curious why!?

Answer (score 7):

You can try this: It works for me.

```
    @interface customTextField : NSTextField
    @property (strong) id target;
    @end

    @implementation customTextField

    - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
    {
        [self sendAction:@selector(clickAction:) to:[self target]];
    }

    @end
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is better to use target's action. You can set it by CTRL+Drag to source code the action.  [self sendAction:self.action to:self.target];

Comment: You should not copy others answer. Its original source is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184555/click-on-nstextfield-label-to-emulate-hyperlink-to-a-folder

Comment: I did not copy , Its coincidence that the link also has given same answer.

Comment: Anoop Vaidya and Verma: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/222029-how-can-use-nstextfield-like-button.html#222519

Answer (score -4):

The method you are looking for is - textShouldBeginEditing:

You have to set the delegate of the NSTextField, first of all.

Comment: Are there any examples I could look at?

Comment: `–control:textShouldBeginEditing:` isn’t sent when the user clicks the text field. It is sent when the user starts typing text in the text field.