# Click on NSTextField Label to emulate hyperlink to a folder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTextField label and I want something to happen when a user clicks on it.

I thought I could create an IBAction and link this to the label but nothing seems to happen.

Any suggestions?

**Intentions:**

The reason why I am doing this is because I want a label that is a hyperlink to a folder. Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach altogether?

**IBAction definition in my PersonController.m**

```
- (IBAction)surnameLabelSelected:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This should do something!");
}
```

**XIB File**

In the XIB file I have made a `Received Actions` connection between `surnameLabelSelected` and the `StaticText` NSTextField label.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Labels are non-editable text fields thus don't send actions to their targets. You want to use an NSButton and turn off its border-drawing and size it to fit its text as best as possible to simulate  a label.

Comment: Good suggestion! Ultimately, I am trying to create a hyperlink field and thought I could modify the label's style to look like a hyperlink. Is your suggestion still the right course of action?

Comment: Unfortunately creating a realistic hyperlink in a text field is a bit more involved than setting a link attribute. I recommend you check out [DSClickableURLTextField](http://www.nightproductions.net/developer.htm#DSClickableURLTextField) for reference.

Comment: This doesn't quite work today. NSButtons love to draw their own background and change their colors depending on their type. There isn't a built in button type and combination of options to eliminate this anymore.

Answer (score 22):

You've got a couple options. Francis's answer is one option. Another option is to subclass NSTextField and override `-mouseDown:`. Something like this (written off the top of my head, not tested):

```
@interface ClickableTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation ClickableTextField

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self sendAction:[self action] to:[self target]];
}

@end
```

If NSTextField is closer in style to the appearance you need, this might be the better approach. If you need NSButton's features (highlight upon click, etc) go with Francis's solution.

Comment: I actually modified DSClickableURLTextField mentioned above to trigger the action exactly as you suggest if there is no URL to open at the area the user clicked. Simple change, thanks for idea.

Comment: It works flawlessly, except maybe for cursor update, but this is easy to work around

Comment: can we check which word tapped in nstextfield

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create a transparent button (without title/image/border, momentary push in) in front of the label, with the same frame as label's. And set button's action accordingly.