# NSButton click not working when there is another control on it like NSLabel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know it seems to be a silly question however its vexed me a lot that's why I am putting it on Stackoverflow. Please be a little lenient.

Here is my `NSButton`:

[image]

there are 2 `NSLabel`s on it

1. showing Name of the button **Installed Apps**
2. showing count of installed apps

**Problem**

When I click near `NSLabel`, the `NSButton` action does not get called.

P.S: I am from *WPF* world of *Microsoft*. There we had `MouseDownPreview` events to handle these type of situations. I don't know much about COCOA. Please help, many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with `NSTextField`. The textfield is drawn on top of the `NSButton` hence it covers it. And click on the area of textfield doesn't send the mouseClick event to `NSButton`.

You can have few ways to cope up with this:

1. Instead of `NSTextField` create `NSButtons` and set the action method of round button.
2. Use a custom `NSTextField` that can [accept mouse click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184555/click-on-nstextfield-label-to-emulate-hyperlink-to-a-folder), and call the round button's action.

> ```
> @interface ClickableTextField : NSTextField
> @end
>
> @implementation ClickableTextField
>
> - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
> {
>     [self sendAction:[self action] to:[self target]];
> }
>
> @end
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSTextField and override following method to return nil.

```
override func hitTest(aPoint: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    return nil
}
```