# Click inside swift 2.2 OSX

Tags: swift, macos

I am having multiple controls like NSTextfields and NSButtons. I couldn't find a solution for touch up inside events in swift 2.2. I tried it with the new selectors but I don't know how to handle touch events with them... Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    textfield.action = #selector(myAction)
    button.action = #selector(myAction)
}

func myAction(sender: NSView)
{
    print("aktuell: \(sender)")
    currentObject = sender
}
```

I am not familiar with the new version of Swift 2.2 so I have no idea how to handle the touch events. I also tried to handle it over the delegate methods but this also didn't work because I have no method for the control if its being touched.

In the older versions of swift I had something like:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("actionMethod"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Error when trying to add the `addTarget` function:

> Value of type 'NSButton' has no member 'addTarget'

But I can't find this in swift 2.2 and there is an error if I am trying to use it.
Thanks for help!

I am using OSX not iOS but this should be the same...

Comment: "*I am using OSX not iOS but this should be the same*". You don't touch things on OSX, you click them.

Comment: Do you know how to add actions in OS X for click event? @DanielStorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `NSButton`'s `action`. For example:

```
let button = NSButton()
button.target = self
button.action = #selector(someAction)
```

From [NSButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButton_Class/):

> NSButton is a subclass of the NSControl class. An NSButton object
>   sends an action message to a target object, such as a view controller,
>   when the button is clicked.

Comment: Does this work for textfields as well?

Comment: @Anokrize [Adding click action to NSTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5588056/2108547).

Comment: Are you able to translate it to swift? I don't understand obj.-c. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Anokrize No, you should learn how to convert Obj-C to Swift. If I answered your question please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Swift2.2 deprecates using strings for selectors and instead introduces new syntax:`#selector`.

For example:

`button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionMethod), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Comment: I can't add the addTarget function somehow.

Comment: see error edit above

Comment: maybe you should check the button's class whether it is `UIControl` or the subclass  of `UIControl`.

Comment: It is OSX I mentioned that already...

Comment: oh sorry, the class `NSControl` is not have the `addTarget`method. try add the target `button.target = self`, `button.action = #selector(myAction)` .