# Creating macOS button from code

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I am trying to create a button for my app by code but I don't know how to program some action. Can somebody help me with it?

My code:

```
var newBut = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 30, height: 30))
newBut.title = "#"
self.view.addSubview(newBut)
```

Xcode version 9.2 (9C40b), Swift 4.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494339/1226963

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click inside swift 2.2 OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494057/click-inside-swift-2-2-osx)