# Single click to edit NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, click, edit, nstextfield

I'm sorry to ask this again, I've looked over all the related questions here, but none seems to help me (or I just can't get it).

Atm, I have an `NSTextField` that operates like every other of its kind, but it needs double-to-triple click to select all of it's content for editing (double selects one word, triple - all of them).

I unfortunately need this to work in a way, that when a user **clicks on it once, all the text gets selected**, so one can start typing a new thing instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you should follow the solutions in this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684166/which-delegate-method-i-should-use-to-respond-to-clicks-on-a-nstextfield)

and once you are in your own derived `-(void) mouseDown: (NSEvent *) theEvent` method, simply select all the text by doing calls to either

[[NSTextField selectText:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/selectText:)

or

[[NSText setSelectedRange:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/setSelectedRange:)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've used the same solution that you linked to.